# Force Crossing Edges in GraphViz

Tags: graph, charts, graphviz, dot

I'm very new to GraphViz and dot (I only started today!), and I'm having a difficult time forcing "crossing edges" (I think that's the term) on my first real graph. Specifically, I'm trying to show that the pins on an electrical component were out of place by one. GraphViz continues to shift one of my clusters downward to avoid crossing the lines, but I want them to cross; I want my clusters to be even and of the same-size. (I'll work on the size part next.)

How can I *force* edge-crossing in GraphViz?

```
digraph {
    rank=same        
    subgraph cluster_designed {
        label="*As Designed*";
        node [shape=square]
        rankdir=TB
        rank=same
        Drain_design -> Gate_design -> Source_design [style=invis];
    }

    subgraph cluster_actual {
        label="*On Chip*";
        node [shape=square]
        rankdir=TB
        rank=same
        Gate_actual -> Source_actual -> Drain_actual [style=invis];
    }

    Drain_design -> Drain_actual;
    Gate_design -> Gate_actual;
    Source_design -> Source_actual;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No simple tweak, it is very difficult to manage the position of clusters.    Instead, I'd suggest using "html-like nodes" (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html).  They are fairly easy to position and seem to produce the result you want.

p.s. **rank=same** applies to subgraphs (not Root)  and **rankdir** applies to Root graph (not subgraphs)

```
digraph {

  {rank=same
  t1 [shape=plaintext,label=<
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="2" CELLPADDING="2" BORDER="1">
  <TR><TD CELLSPACING="5" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0">"as designed"</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD PORT="p1">Drain design</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD PORT="p2">Gate design</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD PORT="p3">Source design</TD></TR>    
  </TABLE>
  >
  ]
  t2 [shape=plaintext,label=<
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="2" CELLPADDING="2" BORDER="1">
  <TR><TD CELLSPACING="5" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0">"On Chip"</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD PORT="p1">Gate Actual</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD PORT="p2">Source Actual</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD PORT="p3">Drain Actual</TD></TR>    
  </TABLE>
  >
  ]

  t1:p1 -> t2:p3
  t1:p2 -> t2:p1
  t1:p3 -> t2:p2
  }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way you know of to insert a LaTeX macro in the HTML? So that I could define stuff like the <TR><TD>...</TD></TR> in a macro to make the end code more readable? @sroush

For example, defining this outside of \diagraph:

\newcommand{\pad}[3]{
<TR><TD PORT="#1" BGCOLOR="#3" ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="CENTER"><font color="#2"><B>Drain</B></font></TD></TR>
}

Comment: Yes, you can preprocess your input file, thought have not read abou using LaTex preprocessor for this.  - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140881/set-pre-defined-node-styles/63142066#63142066